# How to resample an edge of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I was trying to decrease the number of points of a detected edge of an image but I didn't obtain a good result.  I want the result to contain exactly 200 pixels of the edges, but those points must be well chosen so the shape remain very clear. How can I do this?

Here's an example image of what I'm working with:

[image]

Here are some results that I have received with the code I wrote:

[image]

## Code written

```
function y = echantillonnage(x)
contour_image = x;
[lignes,colonnes]=size(x);
n = nombre/200;
contour_image_200px = contour_image;
ok=0;
for i=1:lignes
    for j=1:colonnes
        if (contour_image_200px(i,j)>0 )
                ok=ok+1;
                if ( mod(ok,round(n))>0 )
                   contour_image_200px(i,j)=0;
                end                 
         end      
    end
end
figure,imshow(contour_image_200px);
%résultat
y = contour_image_200px;
end
```

Comment: upload to any image hosting site and post the link

Comment: You can certainly post the code you tried though that would help. Also you may post links to the images and someone will included it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) to trace the boundaries of the objects / edges then sample from those array of points to decrease the number of edge points.  The tracing is done in clockwise order, so you are sure that when you subsample from this array, you will get a semblance of order.  However, `bwboundaries` also returns both **outer** and **inner** contour boundaries, so you only need a certain amount of traces from the output.  We will talk about that later.

`bwboundaries` works for multiple objects, so all you'd have to do is iterate through each object, sample the edge points and write that to an output result.  Note that using `bwboundaries` doesn't even require edges to be found... as long as the object is clean then it isn't necessary.  However, I'm not sure as to the purpose of what you're doing, so let's just operate on the edge detected result.

Let's say we had the following example:

```
>> A = false(256, 256);
>> A(100:170,100:170) = true;
>> A(3:40,3:40) = true;
>> A(190:220,200:230) = true;
>> imshow(A)
```

We get this image:

[image]

If we performed an edge detection:

```
>> B = edge(A, 'canny');
>> imshow(B);
```

We would get this:

[image]

Now, if you want to do the subsampling, you would call `bwboundaries` this way:

```
[bound,L,N] = bwboundaries(B);
```

`bwboundaries` returns a cell array `bound` of boundaries where each cell is a `N x 2` array of spatial coordinates that define the boundary.  The first column are the row locations and the second column are the column locations of the boundary points.  `L` is a label matrix that tells you which point each boundary belongs to.  We don't need this for your purposes but I might as well talk about it.  `N` is the most important parameter.  This defines how many **object** boundaries there are.  This also tells you that the first `N` cells of `bound` tells you that those belong to the outer object boundaries.

As such, you can do the following to subsample your edge points and put them into a new matrix, assuming that your edge image is stored in `B`.  Also, you stated that you want to have 200 points per edge.  Let's define that parameter as `num_edge_points`.  However, if you have edges that are **less** than this amount, then I will assume that you'll just want to have all of the edge points selected.

```
out = false(size(B)); %// Initialize output image
num_edge_points = 200; %// Define number of edge points

%// For each object boundary
for idx = 1 : N
    boundary = bound{idx}; %// Get boundary

    %// Determine how many points we have
    num_pts = size(boundary,1);

    %// Generate indices for sampling the boundary
    %// If there are less than the minimum, just choose this amount
    if num_pts < num_edge_points
        ind = 1:num_pts;
    else
        ind = floor(linspace(1,num_pts,num_edge_points));
    end

    %// Subsample the edge points
    pts = boundary(ind,:);

    %// Mark points in output
    out(sub2ind(size(B), pts(:,1), pts(:,2))) = true;
end
```

`out` will contain your edge image subsampled.  To illustrate that we got this right, let's create a new RGB image where we have the edges and the subsampled edge points on top of each other where the subsampled edges are in red:

```
out_red = 255*uint8(B);
out_greenblue = out_red;
out_greenblue(out) = 0;
out_rgb = cat(3, out_red, out_greenblue, out_greenblue);
imshow(out_rgb);
```

This is what we get (zoomed-in):

[image]

As you can see, the top and bottom rectangles have the full edge points show as there were less than 200 edge points.  However, the one in the middle is sparsely sampled as there are more than 200 edge points, but now we are only displaying 200 of them.

---

If you would like a function to help you facilitate this, you can use the following.  I've essentially copied all of the code above and the input is a binary image with edges and the output is a binary image with the subsampled edges:

```
function [out] = subsample_edge(B)

    %// Obtain boundaries for edge image
    [bound,L,N] = bwboundaries(B);

    out = false(size(B)); %// Initialize output image
    num_edge_points = 200; %// Define number of edge points

    %// For each object boundary
    for idx = 1 : N
        boundary = bound{idx}; %// Get boundary

        %// Determine how many points we have
        num_pts = size(boundary,1);

        %// Generate indices for sampling the boundary
        %// If there are less than the minimum, just choose this amount
        if num_pts < num_edge_points
            ind = 1:num_pts;
        else
            ind = floor(linspace(1,num_pts,num_edge_points));
        end

        %// Subsample the edge points
        pts = boundary(ind,:);

        %// Mark points in output
        out(sub2ind(size(B), pts(:,1), pts(:,2))) = true;
    end
end
```

If you want to call this function, simply do:

```
out = subsample_edge(B);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want the total pixels of the edge to be 200 pixels exactly no matter what the original number is. But I want those points to be well chosen and I want the result to be an image or a binary matrix. How can I modify the code above ?

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm waiting. I modified the question, you can check it if you want . I am beginner and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DeepBlue - Check my code now.  If you're happy, please consider accepting my answer.  Good luck!

Comment: I wasn't able to put all the code in one function that receives a binary picture and return a binary image.What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @DeepBlue - Done... however, I should probably warn you that my code requires the image processing toolbox.  Make sure you have that installed.  My guess is you do because vous avez employé le `imshow`.  Je crois que vous êtes francophone à cause de tes commentaires dans votre code.

Comment: I don't. I have matlab 6.5 . I get an error : ' Undefined function or variable 'bwboundaries'.' What should I install ?  and yes I speak french :)

Comment: Wow.... that's a VERY old version of MATLAB.  `bwboundaries` was released much later than that.  My solution won't work :(  If you want the above code to work, you'll need to upgrade your version of MATLAB.

Comment: @DeepBlue - You probably want the most latest version... but whichever version of MATLAB that can run `bwboundaries`, that's fine :)  I'm currently on MATLAB R2013a on Mac OS.

Comment: okey, thank you very much for your help. I'll buy the newest version and try the code tomorrow. I'll mark your answer as the chosen one now. thank you again.